# Mapping enum field on numeric column with non zero-started values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have a column `timezone` with a constant set of available numeric values [2,3,4,5,6,7,8] (can't change this). So for mapping it seems right to chose some enumerated type with values like:

[Hawaii=2, Alaska=3, Pacific=4, Mountain=5, Central=6, Eastern=7, Atlantic=8]

and map it like: @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)

But my problem is: inability to shift the enumeration start number in java.
As workaround I can fill enum with stubs for shifting. But I find this not flexible & ugly, considering the fact that anyone can call MyEnum.values().

Probably somebody know the appropriate way to use enum in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JPA 2.1 `AttributeConverter` is one way to handle such conversion, and is portable. The `AttributeConverter` would convert between the enum type and Integer. Some JPA providers have their own non-portable handling which you would have to consult the documentation for your provider to see if it offers anything.

See [this issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-47) where better handling for enums in JPA has been requested; not that JPA spec development is active any more.

Comment: Exactly what i looked for. Thanks!